# How can I automatically share certain tasks in Remember the Milk?

Tags: sharing, tasks, remember-the-milk

Remember the Milk makes it really easy to share individual tasks, but how can I make it automatically share certain groups of tasks (e.g., I'd like it to automatically share tasks tagged `#groceries` with my girlfriend).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though that would be awesome - You cannot share a Smart List. You can share a List, or numerous tasks but not a Smart List.

Here is how I would do it.

Search for your tag

```
tag:grocery
```

And either select all your task you want to Share and just share that way (I think you already know this way) The other way, which I use it, is the List. So move your tasks tagged with grocery to a List called Grocery

Then sharing it with allow your friend to change items in your list.

There is a use case for this that worked for a couple.

> My husband and I use a shared RTM list
>   for our grocery shopping. Each of us
>   can put items on the list when we
>   think of it from either work, home or
>   via our smartphones and whoever is
>   doing the shopping always has an
>   up-to-date list. It works especially
>   well as we often stop in to pick up
>   one or two items, but we can also see
>   what else needs to be bought. We use
>   the 'priority' function to separate
>   our items into the general areas of
>   the supermarket, to make it easier to
>   sort through a long list.
>
> As an added bonus, if we are shopping
>   together we can split up and tackle
>   the shopping from different ends of
>   the supermarket. We 'complete' each
>   item on our phones as it goes in the
>   trolley so we don't double up or miss
>   anything. It probably looks a bit
>   strange to other people when we stand
>   in the vegetable section staring at
>   our phones, but it really works well.

source of use case : [Tip & Tricks Forum morgan.parker](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/forums/tips/7644/)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but maybe you can create a [Smart List](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/smartlists/createlist.rtm) for your tag and then [share](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/sharing/sharelist.rtm) it with the appropriate contact.

Comment: -1 for suggesting *he* try something. We all want accurate and complete answers in the stackexchange sites. You'll get +1 from me if you try what you suggested, and report back that it does/doesn't work :)

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow your reasoning, since a) I don't have the problem and b) there is no way for me to test this, since I don't even have a contact (on rmt) to share tasks with. That's really the first time ever that I get a -1 for suggesting a possible solution (on any of the stackexchange sites). Wtf?

Comment: That's really a bit harsh... If he suggests something that no one else (especially the question starter) thought of before it is a valuable answer. If people were to test all their solutions before posting them, most questions would stay unanswered... i mean... isn't this why we can vote up or down working / not working answers? That way the correct "guess" will turn out naturally...

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann Suggestions are better than nothing sometimes, wrong suggestions probably not. Therefore I suggest that if you found the "guessed" solution does not work you can set -1, otherwise do nothing. :)

Comment: On advice from others I have removed my -1. Thanks for helping me learn better behaviour / critique. For that I have up-voted the comments that led to me removing the down vote. :)